# Honeycomb tile map in R

Tags: r, amcharts

How can I implement this honeycomb tile map in R using the `RAmCharts` package (or another package that looks as good)?

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/honeycomb-tile-map/

Comment: None of the examples they have on the "RAmCharts" website show anything like this. Does it really have to use this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy enough to reproduce the figure in R

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- states %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(x = c(-1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1) * 0.5 + x,
          y = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25, -0.5, -0.25, 0.25) * 2/sqrt(3) + y, 
          short, name, value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = value, group = name)) +
  geom_polygon(linewidth = 2, color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = short), data = states) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#fffb77", high = "red", guide = "none") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()

p
```

[image]

You can easily turn this into an interactive plot using `plotly::ggplotly(p)`.

The hard part is getting the data. I took this from the JavaScript object on the linked page and transformed it appropriately for use in R:

```r
states <- structure(list(short = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", 
"CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", 
"KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", 
"NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", 
"RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", 
"WY"), name = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", 
"Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", 
"Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", 
"Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
"Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
"Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", 
"New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", 
"Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", 
"South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", 
"Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), y = c(-5.19615242270663, 
0, -4.33012701892219, -4.33012701892219, -4.33012701892219, -3.46410161513775, 
-2.59807621135332, -3.46410161513775, -3.46410161513775, -6.92820323027551, 
-6.06217782649107, -6.92820323027551, -2.59807621135332, -2.59807621135332, 
-2.59807621135332, -2.59807621135332, -4.33012701892219, -3.46410161513775, 
-5.19615242270663, 0, -3.46410161513775, -1.73205080756888, -1.73205080756888, 
-1.73205080756888, -5.19615242270663, -3.46410161513775, -1.73205080756888, 
-3.46410161513775, -3.46410161513775, -0.866025403784439, -2.59807621135332, 
-5.19615242270663, -1.73205080756888, -4.33012701892219, -1.73205080756888, 
-2.59807621135332, -5.19615242270663, -3.46410161513775, -2.59807621135332, 
-1.73205080756888, -5.19615242270663, -2.59807621135332, -4.33012701892219, 
-6.06217782649107, -4.33012701892219, -0.866025403784439, -4.33012701892219, 
-1.73205080756888, -3.46410161513775, -1.73205080756888, -2.59807621135332
), x = c(7.5, 0.5, 3, 6, 2, 3.5, 11, 9.5, 10.5, 8.5, 8, 0.5, 
2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6.5, 5.5, 11.5, 8.5, 10.5, 7.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 
2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 11, 10, 3.5, 9.5, 9, 3.5, 8, 4.5, 1.5, 9, 11.5, 
8.5, 4, 7, 4, 4, 10, 8, 1.5, 7.5, 5.5, 3), value = c(4849300L, 
737700L, 6745400L, 2994000L, 39250000L, 5540500L, 3596600L, 935600L, 
7288000L, 20612400L, 10310300L, 1419500L, 1634400L, 12801500L, 
6596800L, 3107100L, 2904000L, 4413400L, 4649600L, 1330000L, 6016400L, 
6811700L, 9928300L, 5519900L, 2984900L, 6093000L, 1023500L, 1881500L, 
2839000L, 1326800L, 8944400L, 2085500L, 19745200L, 10146700L, 
739400L, 11614370L, 3878000L, 3970200L, 12784200L, 1055100L, 
4832400L, 853100L, 6651100L, 27862500L, 2942900L, 626010L, 8411800L, 
7288000L, 1850320L, 5778700L, 584150L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
51L))
```

Comment: Great answer! Can you please visit [Customized plotting of PCA results in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517593/customized-plotting-of-pca-results-in-r)? I think you are the right person to answer this.